# Postgresql trigger to check which column(s) value(s) changed?

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers

Need to find which column(s) value(s) have changed in the row before update using postgresql(v.9.5) trigger, Based on the column name, have to either return Null or NEW. How can this be achieved when the number of columns of a table are many?

Answer (score 4):

Use `json` in trigger `FOR EACH ROW`.
Note: use `IS DISTINCT FROM` if old/new value may by `NULL`.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_tr_old_new()
  RETURNS trigger AS $$
DECLARE
  _rec record;
BEGIN
  FOR _rec IN
    SELECT
      o.key
      , o.value AS old_value
      , n.value AS new_value
    FROM json_each(to_json(new)) n
      INNER JOIN json_each(to_json(old)) o ON o.key = n.key
  LOOP
    IF (_rec.old_value::text IS DISTINCT FROM _rec.new_value::text) THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'test_tr_old_new(): Column % changed from ''%'' to ''%''', _rec.key, _rec.old_value, _rec.new_value;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

CREATE TRIGGER old_new
  BEFORE UPDATE
  ON public._tr_table
  FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE public.test_tr_old_new();
```